# Getting GCC 7.2.0 on UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: gcc

I have tried in many ways to download this version on UBUNTU 20.04, some places says I just have to get the GCC7.2.0 packages (which I haven't been able to do), and some places says it is only possible to download GCC7.2.0 on UBUNTU 18.04 which already includes the necessary packages.

Is it even possible? And if it is how do I download?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a chroot or some other type of container (like Docker or systemd-nspawn) of Ubuntu 17.10 artful, which uses GCC 7.2.0 as its system GCC.

You can set up such a container with debootstrap.  Or, you may find that there is a pre-assembled docker image of just what you want already.

Whatever the purpose for you doing this, doing it in some kind of container could be a good idea so that you get the benefit of having GCC set up nicely for you without needing to manually create a toolchain or figure out how to tell build systems how to use a different installed version, but not messing with the system GCC.

At time of writing you haven't given any explanation of why you need a specific GCC version, and it's not usually a common requirement to use an old version of GCC for something like it might be for glibc or some other dependency, but I guess there could be a specific reason.

Comment: I need this version to complete a task as part of company screenings that I am hoping to get into, I really don't know much about Docker or systemd-nspawn, if you can help me out it would be great!